# Why is the average of $\sin^2 wt = 1/2$ and $\cos^2 wt = 1/2$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, means, simple-functions

Why is the average of both $\sin^2 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\cos^2 = \frac{1}{2}$

I was revising Simple Harmonic motion notes and in the average of Kinetic energy derivation

$$KE = \frac12 k  A^2  \cos^2(\omega t)$$

And the solution is given as $\frac{1}{4} kA^2$

I haven't gone that deep in integration help

Comment: What do you know about the sum $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)$?

Comment: Maybe try to go deeper in integration? Or try to use some trigonometric formulae?

Comment: Also, use $\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos 2x$

Comment: The average of either one is the average of the other, since $\cos^2 x=\sin^2(x+\pi/2).$ But the average of $\sin^2+\cos^2$ is obviously $1.$

Comment: BTW, your title is confusing - you seem to be talking about the average value of $\sin^2 x,$ but "the average of $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$ could mean like "the average of $1$ and $3$ is $2.$"

Comment: A look at the graph of $y = \cos^2 x$ makes it intuitively obvious, and also could be used as the inspiration for a proof based on moving areas around.

Comment: Average value of the integrable function $~f(x),~$ in the interval $~[a,b] ~: ~a,b \in \Bbb{R}, ~a < b~$ is defined to be $$\frac{\int_a^b f(x)dx}{b - a}.$$  Then, by symmetry, you know that in the interval $~[0,\pi/2]~$ the average value of $~\cos^2(x)~$ will equal the average value of $~\sin^x(x).~$  Now consider $$\frac{\int_0^{\pi/2} \left[ ~\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) ~\right] ~dx}{\pi/2 - 0} = \frac{\int_0^{\pi/2} 1~dx}{\pi/2 - 0} = 2 \times \text{Average value}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Set $\text{avg}(\cos^2(x))=a$ and $ \text{avg}(\sin^2(x))=b$.
The two functions are horisontal translations of one another, so the averages are the same. $a=b$

It is known that $\forall x:\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$, so $\text{avg}\big(\sin^2(x)\big)+\text{avg}\big(\cos^2(x)\big)=1$, which means that $a+b=1$ so $2a=1$ so $a=\frac12$

$$\text{avg}(\cos^2(x))=\text{avg}(\sin^2(x))=\frac12$$

Q.E.D

Comment: Thank you for that sar , explanation without integration that too , heavy respect.